# Serializing / De-serializing inherited class on a procedural generated loot system (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I have a class called Item that has general info about the item (Name,ID, description)
I inherit from this class to create procedurally Armor / Weapons in my game.
Eg:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item 
{
  public string itemName;
  public string itemID;
  public string itemDescription;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Armor : Item
{
  public int defense;
  public int armorValue;
}
```

In the game, when you kill an enemy, armor class procedurally generates stats and values.

My inventory system has a list of slots, that use Item class as a reference to what item is in the slot.

When I save with Json the slots, and then load again, inheritance does not work, so I get an Item class, with all the base class variables that the Armor class that was "saved" had. I have tried:

1. JsonConver.Serialize, JsonConvert.Deserialize explicitely on each slot (didnt work)
2. Casting Item as Armor if item is armor, that didnt work
3. Using the [JsonConstructor] attribute on the Armor constructor

I am new to Json, Serialization / De-Serialization and I try to read and understand as much as I can so any ideas / leads would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: I solved it by using Dictionaries<string,Armor> storing specifically any armors picked up using Item.ID, so on Equip, takes the armor from the dictionary, no need for casting.

Comment: I would suggest reading Eric Lippers [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) articles. It seem relevant considering the context.

Comment: @JonasH that has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: "JsonConver.Serialize, JsonConvert.Deserialize explicitely on each slot (didnt work)" - what exactly didn't work? What went wrong? Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: Include the code of your trials. That way we can see what you have tried, and may get a better idea of what's not working or what you're looking to achieve in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

@YungDeiza

```
    [System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot
{
    public Item itemInSlot //Item is the base class

    //First the slot is initialized with the normal JsonUtilities.FromJson, from my SaveLoad class. That works. 
    //I now have a reference to the Item so also Access to the item.ID


    //This is how I tested JsonConvert.Serialize/Desirialize
    public void SaveSlot()
    {
        if(item is Armor)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(item as Armor);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(item.ID, json);
        }
    }

    public void LoadSlot()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey(item.ID))
        {
            var json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(item.ID);
            var armor = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<Armor>(json);
            item = new Armor(armor); //I have made a constructor for the Armor class that takes an Armor and "copies" it
        }
    }   
}
```

That is my Save system:

```
    public static class SaveLoad
{
    public static UnityAction OnSaveGame;
    public static UnityAction<SaveData> OnLoadGame;

    public const string SaveDirectory = "/SaveData/";
    private const string FileName = "Save.sav";

     
    public static bool Save(SaveData saveData)
    {
        OnSaveGame?.Invoke();

        string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + SaveDirectory;

        GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = dir;
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData, true);
     

        File.WriteAllText(dir + FileName, json);

        return true;
    }

    public static void DeleteSavedData()
    {
        string fullPath = Application.persistentDataPath + SaveDirectory + FileName;
        if (File.Exists(fullPath)) File.Delete(fullPath);
    }

    public static SaveData Load()
    {
        string fullPath = Application.persistentDataPath + SaveDirectory + FileName;
        SaveData data = new SaveData();

        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(json);
            OnLoadGame?.Invoke(data);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Save File Does not exist");
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

And hereby what is the data is saved:

```
  [System.Serializable]
public void PlayerData
{
    //Banch of stats - intergers
    
    public InventorySystem inventorySystem; 

    public PlayerData()
    {
      //Stats are initialized
      inventorySystem = new InventorySystem(x); //I have a default inventory size of 24
    }
}

    [System.Serializable]
public void InventorySystem
{
    public List<InventorySlots> inventorySlots;

    public void InventorySystem(int size)
    {
        inventorySlots = new List<InventorySlots>(size);
    }
}
```

As I said, when an enemy is killed, he drops an armor, and the armor class itself, just calculates random stats. The saveload method normally saves the Armor, and I can see it in my inventory, but I used a Debug.Log(item.GetType), and it always loads it as an Item class and not an Armor class. I ve read a lot, and as far as I can understand, Unity serialization and JsonUtilities, dont really support inheritance. So I m not sure where to look now.

Thank you in advance, I hope I helped understand my issue a bit better

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Newtonsoft's JSON serializer. It supports subclasses:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(serializedString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will look into it, it is been a while since I ve worked on this little project